# Is the "what if I run at full throttle all the time" question low quality?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, low-quality

[What happens if the engines were kept on full throttle all flight long? (except for the approach and landing)](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/86991/what-happens-if-the-engines-were-kept-on-full-throttle-all-flight-long-except)

This question received a negative score and was flagged as low quality. But while I understand that the question is very, very basic, what makes it unsuitable for an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Things that stand out as low quality, in my opinion

1. Very short 1 sentence. Therefore the question lacks clarity, context and purpose. It is hastily written without much real thought.
2. "Engine" is a very broad term. Ok it is *tagged* [jet-engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jet-engine) (after a clarification/edit) but there are so many different jet engines, all able to cope differently with different operating modes.